# Convert Date format r programming

Tags: r, date

converting a string to date

```
date_string <- c("1st December 2019" , "2nd December 2019" , "3rd December 2019" ,"4th November 2019" 

, "20th November 2019")

date_string_new <- as.Date(date_string, format= "%d %B %Y")
```

But the output is "1st December 2019"   "2nd December 2019"   "3rd December 2019"
[4] "4th Novemeber 2019"  "20th Novemeber 2019"

```
[1] NA NA NA NA NA
```

Ideally is

```
[1] "1 December 2019"   "2 December 2019"   "3 December 2019"  
[4] "4 Novemeber 2019"  "20 Novemeber 2019
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can just remove the characters after the digits with `sub` and use `as.Date` from `base R`

```
as.Date(sub("[a-z]+", "", date_string), "%d %B %Y") 
#[1] "2019-12-01" "2019-12-02" "2019-12-03" "2019-11-04" "2019-11-20"
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you might consider `lubridate` package for date conversions:

```
library(lubridate)

date_string_new <- dmy(date_string)

R> date_string_new
[1] "2019-12-01" "2019-12-02" "2019-12-03" "2019-11-04" "2019-11-20"
```

This will store the date results as class `Date`.

Answer (score 1):

In base R, you can do

```
as.Date(sub('(\\d+).*?\\s(.*)', '\\1\\2', date_string), "%d%B%Y")
#[1] "2019-12-01" "2019-12-02" "2019-12-03" "2019-11-04" "2019-11-20"
```

---

If you want output in the same format, you can try

```
sub('(\\d+).*?\\s(.*)', '\\1 \\2', date_string)
#[1] "1 December 2019"  "2 December 2019"  "3 December 2019"  "4 November 2019"  "20 November 2019"
```

Or

```
sub('st|nd|rd|th', "", date_string)
```